# How to tell if it is honey, super filtered honey, or corn syrup?

Tags: syrup, honey, glucose-syrup

There is this article here in Australia that an importer has labeled corn syrup as honey. It has been imported from Turkey and it has been sold to people. I think this is not just happening here in the land of OZ. Just with a little bit of searching I found out that there is some international conspiracy against the humble bees and people messing up the natural processes. There is even super filtered honey that does not have any pollen at all. I always thought the pollen is the most important part of honey. You might as well just have corn syrup instead.

I would like to know if there is a any way to tell the difference between corn syrup, super filtered honey, and natural honey.

The article:
https://au.finance.yahoo.com/news/honey-actually-corn-vic-buyers-100510448.html

Comment: natural honey has pollen -- but it's possible that something with pollen in it is pure honey (it could be diluted).  Most groups filter the honey because that allows them to hide the country of origin.  (many countries ban honey from china or india)

Comment: @Joe That's interesting. What is it about honey from those countries that triggered the bans?

Comment: For China, it was [stiff tariffs, plus traces of lead and antibiotics, and mislabeled product](http://healthland.time.com/2011/08/22/tainted-chinese-honey-may-be-on-u-s-store-shelves/).  The India ban is [also for antibiotics](http://wonderwoman.intoday.in/story/unhealthy-bitter-truths-about-honey-in-india!/1/86477.html), but there are also concerns that they ramped up exports so quickly after the US tarrifed Chinese honey that they're actually just relabeling it & passing it on.

Comment: @Joe I just checked the label on my monster-sized bottle from Sam's Club. Produced and bottled in Iowa. YAY! (SueBee White Clover)

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey#Physical_and_chemical_properties ... I'm not sure, but I don't think corn syrup will crystallize. In fact, its often added to prevent sugar crystallization.

Comment: I do not think anyone needs to worry about ["ultrapurified" honey](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thesalt/2011/11/25/142659547/relax-folks-it-really-is-honey-after-all). "This is a standard, widely used process. It removes all the pollen, along with dust, bees' wings, and, of course, the diatomaceous earth." Going further down in the article we see that "Consumers don't tend to like crystallized honey" at least in the US. Manufacturers in the US take out crystalizing agents of honey (which includes pollen, apparently) so that it does not crystalize.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to tell at home. You need a laboratory.

Comment: I always thought if honey crystallizes it is a good thing and shows it is not processed. Personally I use Ironbark and Leatherwood honey. The Leatherwood crystallizes very quickly, maybe in 2 or three month. It has a strong flavor,my favorite, but Ironbark is milder and does not crystallize even after a year or two.

Comment: Surely flavor is the easiest way to tell the difference between corn syrup and honey? I know some people wouldn't know, but if you actually like honey and have had real honey, I'm pretty sure you could tell the difference.

Comment: If you cannot tell corn syrup from honey by tasting it, why would you spend money on buying the more expensive honey? I pay lots of money to buy good honey, usually honey made from specific plants (yields). I prefer fir, chestnut, and thyme, which are dark and have a rich flavor. You can easily tell such honey from other yields just by tasting it. (If you prefer other kinds, it might not be that easy to tell it from corn syrup.) Anyway, I think the bottom line is: But where you trust, learn what it tastes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying local honey is one way to be sure that what you are getting is "honey".  I've never heard of people passing off something else as honey.  Isn't that why we have the fda?  If you are buying it in the store, check the lable... my honey has one ingredient; honey.

Comment: I don't mean to be argumentative, but just because you've never heard of it happening doesn't mean it never happens. Also, the asker mentions imported "honey" from Turkey, where producers aren't bound by the rules of the FDA.

Comment: I think it's unfortunate that this answer has been so trounced for half of the message. "buy local honey" is good advice.

Comment: Just to add to other comments, honey adulteration is *very* hard to detect with modern honey processing techniques (see this [related question](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/57155/15018), and many honey processors in various countries apparently aren't bothering to do thorough checks on sources.  It may not be typical pass off something *completely* different (e.g., sugar syrup) as "honey," but it's quite possible to add some percentage of other sugars to "stretch" the honey. Often such additions can only be detected with complex lab testing.